# Add custom field in .NET 6 Microsoft tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-6.0

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) on the Microsoft website.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2020 and .NET 6 Web MVC, I followed the instructions and all look ok till this line:

```
var user = new CateringMilanoUser
            {
                Name = Input.Name,
                DOB = Input.DOB,
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email
            };
```

When I generated the code with visual studio I found it different :

```
var user = CreateUser();
```

Do you know how to implement the CreateUser with those two new fiedls?

Comment: Which 2 new fields?

Comment: Hi phuzi, Name = Input.Name,
                DOB = Input.DOB,

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `CreateUser`

Comment: There is not.. i do not know how to handle it.. i mean i just need to add two field to the registration form but it looks very hard.. i added them in the view inside the code register.cs but i do not know how to save them when the var user = CreateUser(); is called... have you got a simpre example ho to implement in NET 6 ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set values before calling the CreateAsync Method.

```
var user = CreateUser();

user.DOB = Input.DOB;
user.Name = Input.Name;

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```